# I am trying to read a file and copy every character read into a character array and print it in JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file and copy every character as it is read into a character array and then print it.
The output is just displaying the last character read from the file.

Text in file : "kgdsfhgsdfbsdafj**b**

output on screen : **b**

Kindly suggest if anything is wrong.

My code :

```
char pt[] = new char[count];

//File is opened again and this time passed into the plain text array 
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("/Documents/file1.txt") ;

int s ;

while((s = f.read()) != -1 )            
{
    int ind = 0;

    pt[ind] = (char) s ;
    ind ++ ;                
}

for( int var = 0 ; var < pt.length ; var++)         
{
    System.out.print(pt[var]) ;
} 

f.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int ind = 0;` should be before the loop.

```
int ind = 0;
while((s = f.read()) != -1 )
{    
    pt[ind] = (char) s ;
    ind ++ ;

}
```

As it is now, you read each character into `pt[0]`, so only the last character remains in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Take `int ind = 0` line out of the loop.
The way you have it now, it is resetting the index back to zero at every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to the following:

```
int ind = 0;

while ((s = f.read()) != -1) {

    pt[ind] = (char) s;
    ind++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It still won't work, there'll be an out of bounds exception.

The error lies in the line

```
        pt[ind] = (char) s;
```

Comment: There *could* be. It depends on `count`.

Comment: Maybe you should describe *why* there will an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` first.